# Data from firebase not loading on route change, but does on refresh

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularFire with Angular to update some views but the strange thing is when I switch from view to view the data doesn't load, but when I refresh the page it does. What's going on?

WizardController:

```
/* initialize data */

var ref = new Firebase('https://dlwj.firebaseio.com/');

/* set data to automatically update on change */

$scope.currentLocation = $route.current.$$route.originalPath;
$scope.propertyRef = $firebase(ref);

$scope.propertyRef.$on('loaded', function(value) {

  //value will be undefined when I switch views using hash routes.
  //there is no issue when I just refresh on that page.
  console.log(value); 
  $scope.propertyConfiguration = value.products;
  var products = [];
  for (var key in value.products) {
    if (value.products.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      products.push(key);
    }
  }

  $scope.productsArray = products;

});

console.log('Data retrieved');
```

Routes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/SharedProperties',
{
  templateUrl: 'partials/SharedPropertiesPartial.html',
  controller: 'WizardController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/Registration',
{
  templateUrl: 'partials/Registration.html',
  controller: 'WizardController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/Login',
{
  templateUrl: 'partials/Login.html',
  controller: 'WizardController'
});
```

Comment: What version of angularFire is this? Why are the values being pushed into an array inside 'loaded' rather than letting $firebase handle the sync into $scope.products? Why are we using an array? What happens if you put your console.log inside the loaded callback; it only fires on reload and not view switch, right?

Comment: The version is 0.6.0. I'm not sure what you mean by $firebase handling the sync but I'm using firebase as a static-data source so I don't expect productsArray to change. The console.log() inside the 'loaded' callback always runs, it'll either output undefined on a view2view switch, or the actual data on a page refresh.

Comment: Try putting console.log inside the loaded callback (it's currently outside that method).

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding but would that be like `$scope.propertyRef.$on('loaded', function(){console.log()});` ? B/c there's already one there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to download the data using a wrapper lib like $firebase (which takes care of synchronization and such) and then immediately pull that data out and put it into a different scope object.

Just declare your scope var:

```
$scope.products = $firebase(ref);
```

And to use it:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderByPriority">{{product|json}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to iterate the data in a controller or service:

```
$scope.products = $firebase(ref);

// some time later, probably in $scope.products.$on('loaded')...
// note that $getIndex() is only useful here to get the keys in
// the order they appear in the database, otherwise, forEach($scope.products, ...)
// is sufficient
angular.forEach($scope.products.$getIndex(), function(key) {
   console.log(key, $scope.products[key]);
});
```

If you want to use Firebase as a static database (which is quite baffling to a lover of all things real-time like myself) and not be notified each time there is a change, you can simply do the following:

```
angular.controller('MyController', function($timeout, $scope) {
   new Firebase('<URL>').once('value', function(snap) {
      $timeout(function() {
         $scope.products = snap.val();
      });
   });
});
```

And then utilize it normally:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(key,product) in products">{{key}}: {{product|json}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Kato, for the extra detailed answer as usual! I had actually forgotten about (key,products) and all my looping was just a hacky way of trying to get key. Are you sure that your `$scope.products[key]` works though? It prints undefined for me. It's very similar to the issue [here](http://bit.ly/1n3dG87) where the object prints as `{$method1,$method2,property1,property2}` in the console, but object.property1 prints out undefined.

Comment: Found your answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/dYpCAH94y7Y) :) Needed to wrap the code in $on('loaded'). It's somewhat tricky working with async calls.

Comment: Ah, right, you would need to wrap that in $on('loaded'). Have to remember not to code in shorthand :)

Comment: Why the `$timeout` inside the `.once()`, @Kato?

Comment: @Kato is right, I had the same problem and came up with the same solution as here. It just works.

Comment: @MurraySmith the $timeout notifies Angular to re-run it's compiler; there is no way for angular to automagically know we've updated a JavaScript variable (yet), so somebody has to tell it. [Read more about the compiler here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) and also see $timeout and $apply's docs for a quick explanation.